# Changeable thickness of lines within table

Tags: tables

I am working on a table that @David Carlisle fixed for me in this topic: [Formatting pbox in table for neat distribution of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225198/formatting-pbox-in-table-for-neat-distribution-of-text) The tex for the table is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\pb[1]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{SOME TEXT HERE}           & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Big title that takes the whole page} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MORE TEXT}                           & number    & number    & number \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number    & number    & number         \\ \hline
some title here          & value       &\pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}& \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}   &    \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number    & number    & number    \\ \hline
some title here         & value                     &  \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 228}& \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}   &  \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number    & number    & number     \\ \hline
some title here         & value l                     &   \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}& \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}  & \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{There should be proper caption.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

What I am trying to do now is to make it more readable. In order to do so I wanted to make some of the lines thicker that the other. The problem is that I want the thickness to be changeable within table, which is a bit harder to achieve. Here is an exemplary look of the table:

[image]

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: One key to readability of tables is avoiding vertical lines. The documentation of `booktabs` has some nice explanations. Right now, this table looks a bit like sieve on an LSD trip.

Comment: A bit less drastic, http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=14647777#14647777

Comment: :-) Well this table is ineed unreadable and looks ugly, but the table i presented is one third of the actual table and i want to use bold lines to separate each part, so the data is exposed better, so the screen is just an example so that I can modify the code to my own needs, because doing it from scratch is a bit too hard for me.

Comment: removing the lines is probably an improvement but if you want thick and thin an easy way is to use `||` for thick vertical and `\hline\hline` for thick horizontal, setting `\setlength\doublerulesep{0pt}` so they make a thick rule rather than a double rule

Comment: P.S. I like your link Johannes_B, I might reconsider the design

Comment: The `tabu` package, about which I know next to nothing, can do mixed line thickness.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223329/tabu-package-gaps-in-vertical-lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution, using the `\Xhline` and `\Xcline` commands from `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\newcommand\thickvrule[1][2pt]{\vrule width #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{tabular}{!{\thickvrule}l|l!{\thickvrule}*{2}{l|}l!{\thickvrule}}\Xhline{2pt}
\multicolumn{2}{!{\thickvrule}l!{\thickvrule}}{SOME TEXT HERE} & \multicolumn{3}{l!{\thickvrule}}{Big title that takes the whole page} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{!{\thickvrule}l!{\thickvrule}}{MORE TEXT} & number & number & number \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{!{\thickvrule}l!{\thickvrule}}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number & number & number \\ \Xcline{1-2}{1.2pt}\Xcline{3-5}{2pt}
some title here & value &\makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}& \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} & \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} \\
\Xcline{1-2}{1.2pt}\Xcline{3-5}{2pt}
\multicolumn{2}{!{\thickvrule}l!{\thickvrule}}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number & number & number \\ \Xcline{1-2}{1.2pt}\Xcline{3-5}{2pt}
some title here & value & \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 228}& \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} & \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} \\ \Xcline{1-2}{1.2pt}\Xcline{3-5}{2pt}
\multicolumn{2}{!{\thickvrule}l!{\thickvrule}}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number & number & number \\ \Xcline{1-2}{1.2pt}\Xcline{3-5}{2pt}
some title here & value l & \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}& \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} & \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} \\ \Xhline{2pt}
\end{tabular}
\caption{There should be proper caption.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. In that environment, the key `hvlines` draws all the rules excepted in the `\multicolumn`. Morever, `nicematrix` creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, row and columns of the array. So, it's possible to add whatever rule you want with Tikz. In the following code, I have drawn the thick rules with Tikz after the construction of the tabular.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=2pt}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{NiceTabular}{lllll}[hvlines]
\multicolumn{2}{l}{SOME TEXT HERE} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Big title that takes the whole page} \\ 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{MORE TEXT} & number & number & number \\ 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number & number & number \\ 
some title here & value &\makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}& \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} & \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number & number & number \\ 
some title here & value & \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 228}& \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} & \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} \\ 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number & number & number \\ 
some title here & value l & \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}& \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} &
\makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} \\ 
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw [very thick] 
            (1-|1) rectangle (9-|6) 
            (1-|3) -- (9-|3) 
            (4-|3) -- (4-|6) 
            (5-|3) -- (5-|6) 
            (6-|3) -- (6-|6) 
            (7-|3) -- (7-|6) 
            (8-|3) -- (8-|6) ;
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{There should be proper caption.}
\end{table}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]